# Vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector

I need to initialize a vector of pair with (false,false) in each pair of length n.

Something like this, but correct:

```
vector<pair<bool,bool> > hm(n,(false,false));
```

Comment: Is it in Java? Please include the language of your choice!

Comment: Looks like C++ to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++03 compatible answer:

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool,bool> > hm(n, std::make_pair(false, false));
```

Comment: For C++11 (or newer), see G.Samaras' excellent answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Initialize a vector of n pairs in one line like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<bool, bool> > hm{n, {false, false}};
```

Comment: +1: with the stress placed on `{` instead of `(` :)

Comment: Thanks @quetzalcoatl, typo found!

Comment: Too much typing for my liking ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`std::pair` value initializes its members, which means that a default construction will set both members to `false`. So this will have the desired effect:

```
vector<pair<bool,bool>> hm(n);
```